# Neural Network hidden nodes for continuous DV

Tags: neural-network

I am working on a dataset with 420k observations and 7 independent continuous variables. My dependent variable (DV) is a continuous one also. I want to use a neural network to predict my DV. I want to know if there is a rule of selecting how many hidden nodes to consider for correctly predicting the output variable which is continuous. Any reference to a paper would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of hidden nodes in an NN is a hyperparameter. As far as I know, there are no papers that tell us what should be the number of hidden nodes. There are papers which suggest some number but again those numbers are application and architecture specific. I suggest you try increasing the number of nodes and check the accuracy because as the number of nodes increases, it's more likely that model overfits our data. I would suggest you go for trial and error method. Apart from this if there is some other answer I would be glad to know.

Answer (score 1):

There are many rule-of-thumb methods for determining an acceptable number of neurons to use in the hidden layers, such as the following:

1. The number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input layer and the size of the output layer.
2. The number of hidden neurons should be 2/3 the size of the input layer, plus the size of the output layer.
3. The number of hidden neurons should be less than twice the size of the input layer.

These three rules provide a starting point for you to consider. Ultimately, the selection of an architecture for your neural network will come down to trial and error.

You can  [refer](https://www.heatonresearch.com/2017/06/01/hidden-layers.html) this article.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will refer to the article.